# Shiny manipulating input$df with reactive

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and trying to modify this code to allow for the function to be used from a dynamically selected csv.

```
## function to return random row number from data set
getTweet <- function(){
 tweetData[sample(nrow(tweetData), 1), ]
}

our_tweet <- isolate(appVals$tweet)
  output$tweet <- renderText({ our_tweet$tweet })
  output$screen_name <- renderText({ our_quote$screen_name })
  output$resultsTable <- renderDataTable({appVals$ratings})
```

The above code works when tweetData is a static csv read in through read.csv() but when I try to use a drop down to select csv the only way I am able to run without error is putting it inside of a renderDataTable() function. How could I use reactive values within input$file and still be able to run the above code.

Code using renderDataTable():

```
 output$test <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$file)
    csvName <- paste0('../path/to/file/', input$file)
    selectedData <- read.csv(csvName)
    selectedData
    })
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
csvName <- paste0('../path/to/file/', input$file)
selectedData <- read.csv(csvName)

selectedData[sample(nrow(selectedData), 1), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create `reactive` functions:

```
csvName <- reactive(paste0('../path/to/file/', input$file))
selectedData <- reactive(read.csv(csvName()))
```

You can then use the reactive functions in other reactives like `renderDataTable`:

```
output$test <- renderDataTable({
  selectedData()[sample(nrow(selectedData()), 1), ]
    })
```

Don't forget the `()` when calling the result of reactive functions : `csvName()`, `selectedData()`, , ...

Comment: @mk2080, did it answer your question?